# How to add file filter using Kendo v2016

Tags: javascript, html, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to see how to add a file filter in Kendo.Mvc.UI.FileUpload. I have found some examples online but all of them use a method called 'select', and the current version of Kendo I am using does not appear to have this method. I am trying to isolate the file types allowed to be chosen to .pdf and .csv files.

What I am currently doing also, is using kendo in the razor syntax not in javascript, so a basic file upload is being done as the example shows below:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                      .Name("chkfiles")
                      .Async(a => a
                  .Save("SaveCF", "AccountEvent", new { id = Model.SeqNum })
                  .Remove("RemoveCF", "AccountEvent", new { id = Model.SeqNum })
                          .AutoUpload(true)

                      ).Files(f =>
                      {
                          if (Model != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CheckListFile))
                          {
                              f.Add().Name(Path.GetFileName(Model.CheckListFile));
                          }
                      })
                      .Multiple(false)
                          .Events(e =>
                          {
                              e.Error("accountEventEditController.uploadCheckFileError");
                              e.Upload("accountEventEditController.onCheckFileUpload");
                              e.Success("accountEventEditController.onCheckFileSuccess");
                              e.Remove("accountEventEditController.onCheckFileRemove");
                              e.Complete("accountEventEditController.onCheckFileComplete");
                          })
                    )
```

How can I extend this possibly or or check to filter files before it uploads. I have read that you cannot filter the file dialog that opens but can call e.preventdefault() if file type selected is incorrect. But how do I incorperate this, or how can I edit the file input html that is created by the kendo fileupload widget. Then I can possibly just add the attribute params such as below:

```
accept=".xls,.xlsx"
```

Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Man I have been looking for a while, but right after posting think I found the answer. I didn't know there was a validation param, so going to try it out now.

Comment: Is not appearing to work. Why can I not use validation when using this in razor, instead of in javascript format to call kendo?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can subscribe to the select event, then return preventdefault() if file type is incorrect.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                  .Name("chkfiles")
                  .Async(a => a
              .Save("SaveCF", "AccountEvent", new { id = Model.SeqNum })
              .Remove("RemoveCF", "AccountEvent", new { id = Model.SeqNum })
                      .AutoUpload(true)

                  ).Files(f =>
                  {
                      if (Model != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CheckListFile))
                      {
                          f.Add().Name(Path.GetFileName(Model.CheckListFile));
                      }
                  })
                  .Multiple(false)
                      .Events(e =>
                      {
                          e.Error("accountEventEditController.uploadCheckFileError");
                          e.Upload("accountEventEditController.onCheckFileUpload");
                          e.Success("accountEventEditController.onCheckFileSuccess");
                          e.Remove("accountEventEditController.onCheckFileRemove");
                          e.Complete("accountEventEditController.onCheckFileComplete");

                          e.Select("accounteventcontroller.onSelectFile");
                      })
                )
```

OR to answer my HtmlAttributes section:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                      .Name("chkfiles")                          
                      .Async(a => a
                  .Save("SaveCF", "AccountEvent", new { id = Model.SeqNum })
                  .Remove("RemoveCF", "AccountEvent", new { id = Model.SeqNum })
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { accept = ".pdf, .csv" })
                   .AutoUpload(true))
                   .Files(f =>
                      {
                          if (Model != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CheckListFile))
                          {
                              f.Add().Name(Path.GetFileName(Model.CheckListFile));
                          }
                      })
                  .Multiple(false)
                  .Events(e =>
                    {
                              e.Error("accountEventEditController.uploadCheckFileError");
                              e.Upload("accountEventEditController.onCheckFileUpload");
                              e.Success("accountEventEditController.onCheckFileSuccess");
                              e.Remove("accountEventEditController.onCheckFileRemove");
                              e.Complete("accountEventEditController.onCheckFileComplete");
                          })

                    )
```